# NOT LIKE multiple OR statements?

Tags: php, mysql

if have a mailing script that i've set to throttle domains i send to. the remaining domains that do not have a throttle rate set, get assigned a default rate. to find domains which do NOT match an existing throttled domain, i use this php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mailer_lists` ml JOIN `mailer_controller` mc";
        $query .= " ON ml.project_name = mc.project_name";
        $query .= " WHERE `email` NOT LIKE '%";
        $query .= "" . implode("' OR '%", $throttle_domain) . "'";
        echo "$query";
```

the output of the echo is:

```
SELECT * FROM `mailer_lists` ml JOIN `mailer_controller` mc ON ml.project_name = mc.project_name WHERE `email` NOT LIKE '%gmail.com' OR '%hotmail.com' OR '%yahoo.com' OR '%aol.com'
```

as far as i can tell the output looks perfectly fine. i ran a test query in phpmyadmin and only the first domain applies. anything after the OR is ignored.

is there something obviously wrong with this query that i'm missing? can't you use multiple OR statements while using the NOT LIKE statement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would do

```
where substring_index(`email`,'@',-1) not in ('yahoo.com','gmail.com')
```

and so on.

Comment: Nice method. Never thought to use the `substring_index`, +1 for that!

Answer (score 4):

You're taking mySQL's "human language" approach too far. :)  Each `OR` is interpreted as an expression of its own, not as a value to do a `LIKE` against.

Also, I think you want to use `AND`. Using `OR` will always apply to *every* row.

Try

```
    (`email` NOT LIKE "%gmail.com") 
AND (`email` NOT LIKE "%hotmail.com") 
AND (`email` NOT LIKE "%yahoo.com") ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You must repeat the `field_name not like` part :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mailer_lists` ml 
    JOIN `mailer_controller` mc ON ml.project_name = mc.project_name 
WHERE 
    `email` NOT LIKE '%gmail.com' 
    and `email` NOT LIKE '%hotmail.com' 
    and `email` NOT LIKE '%yahoo.com' 
    and `email` NOT LIKE '%aol.com' 
LIMIT 50
```

*(And you probably have to use `and`, instead of `or`, between the conditions)*